# Is there a pure Javascript similar this code $('#date1',this.el)[0]?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have an app, I build with Backbone and Marionette, I think this is a jQuery function or something like that, I found this code on marionette View

```
$('#publicdate',this.el)[0]
```

Is there a similar with that code in pure Javascript? I have tried this code

```
document.getElementById('date1')
this.getElementById('date1')
```

but not working

**Here the full code:**

```
programming.module("Program.Chart", function(Chart, programming, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){  
    Chart.chartT = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template : "#row",
        tagName : "tr"
    })

    Chart.chartV = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        childView : Chart.chartT,
        childViewContainer : "tbody#detail",
        template : "#chart",
        onRender : function(){  
        //DatePicker Range
            var
            startDate,
            endDate,
            updateStartDate = function() {
                startPicker.setStartRange(startDate);
                endPicker.setStartRange(startDate);
                endPicker.setMinDate(startDate);
            },
            updateEndDate = function() {
                startPicker.setEndRange(endDate);
                startPicker.setMaxDate(endDate);
                endPicker.setEndRange(endDate);
            },
            startPicker = new Pikaday({
                field: $('#date1',this.el)[0],
                minDate: new Date(),
                maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
                onSelect: function() {
                    startDate = this.getDate();
                    updateStartDate();
                }
            }),
            endPicker = new Pikaday({
                field: $('#date2',this.el)[0],
                minDate: new Date(),
                maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
                onSelect: function() {
                    endDate = this.getDate();
                    updateEndDate();
                }
            }),
            _startDate = startPicker.getDate(),
            _endDate = endPicker.getDate();
            if (_startDate) {
                startDate = _startDate;
                updateStartDate();
            }
            if (_endDate) {
                endDate = _endDate;
                updateEndDate();
            }   

        var selectdate = $('#publicdate',this.el)[0];
        selectdate.addEventListener("change",function(){
            alert("Changed")
        })




        //Chart JS
        var dataChart = programming.request("data:entities");
        console.log(dataChart.models)

        var labels = ['12/08/2016','13/08/2016','16/08/2016']
        var series = [[100,210,311],[49,10,7]]

        var data = {
            labels : labels,
            series : series
        }

        var option = {
            showArea : true,
            lineSmooth : false,
            chartPadding : {
                bottom:30,
                top:30
            },
            axisX : {
                showGrid:false
            },
            axisY : {  
            },
            plugins : [
                Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle({
                    axisX: {
                       axisTitle: 'Tanggal',
                       axisClass: 'ct-axis-title',
                       offset: {
                          x: 0,
                          y: 50
                       },
                       textAnchor: 'middle'
                    },
                    axisY: {
                       axisTitle: 'Jumlah Penjualan',
                       axisClass: 'ct-axis-title',
                       offset: {
                          x: 0,
                          y: 0
                       },
                       textAnchor: 'middle',
                       flipTitle: false
                     }
                }),
                Chartist.plugins.ctPointLabels({
                    textAnchor : "middle"
                })
            ]
        }
        new Chartist.Line($('.statistic',this.el)[0],data,option)
        }
    })

    Chart.notfound = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template : "#notfound"
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The getElementById should have worked. Maybe you used the wrong id.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a similar with that code in pure Javascript?

That *is* pure JavaScript. But if you want to do it with the DOM rather than with jQuery, you can use `querySelector`:

```
this.el.querySelector('#publicdate')
```

...assuming `this.el` is an HTML element.

`querySelector` is available both on `document` and on individual elements. When you use it on an element, it looks only within that element's tree. It accepts any valid CSS selector, and returns a reference to the first matching element, or `null`. So the above does exactly what the jQuery code did (other than giving you `null` instead of `undefined` if not found): Finds an element with `id="publicdate"` *only if* it exists in `this.el`'s tree.

There's also `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of matching elements. Both are supported on all modern browsers, and also IE8.

> I have tried this code
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('date1')
> ```
>
> but not working

Well, `date1` and `publicdate` are different IDs. But the big difference between `document.getElementById("publicdate")` and `this.el.querySelector("#publicdate")` is, again, that the latter will find the element only if it exists within the descendant tree of `this.el`, whereas `getElementById` will find it anywhere in the document.